# Calculating a windowed weighted moving average where each observation has its own weight

Tags: r, tidyverse, moving-average

I'm trying to calculate a windowed weighted moving average, with a window value of n. I essentially have a set of products, a price for each id, and a reference. I then calculate the ratio of the price with respect to the reference. (price = 45, reference = 45, distance = 1)
From this calculation I then obtain a weight for each observation. I would like to compare results when doing a simple moving average of all the prices and a weighted moving average.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(id = c(1:15),
       price = c(40,50,34,56,78,35,23,40,50,34,56,78,35,23,12),
       product = c(sample(c("A","B"), 15, replace = TRUE)),
       reference = 45,
       distance = price / reference)

max_weight = 1
min_weight = 0

max_distance = 1
min_distance = 0

df <- df %>%
  mutate(weight = case_when(
    distance < 1 ~ (min_weight * (min_distance - distance) + max_weight * (distance - max_distance)) / (min_distance - max_distance) ,
    TRUE ~ 1
  )
  )


> df %>%
+   head()
# A tibble: 6 x 6
     id price product reference distance weight
  <int> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1    40 B              45    0.889  0.111
2     2    50 B              45    1.11   1    
3     3    34 B              45    0.756  0.244
4     4    56 A              45    1.24   1    
5     5    78 B              45    1.73   1    
6     6    35 A              45    0.778  0.222
```

Moving Average calculation:

```r
moving_average <- function(x,n){stats::filter(x, c(0, rep(1/n,n)), sides=1) }

df <- df %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  mutate(moving_average = moving_average(price, n =3))


> df %>%
+   head()
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   product [2]
     id price product reference distance weight moving_average
  <int> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>
1     1    40 B              45    0.889  0.111           NA  
2     2    50 B              45    1.11   1               NA  
3     3    34 B              45    0.756  0.244           NA  
4     4    56 A              45    1.24   1               NA  
5     5    78 B              45    1.73   1               41.3
6     6    35 A              45    0.778  0.222           NA
```

Essentially, the last step would be to calculate a moving average such that:

sum(price_i * weight_i) / sum(weight_i)

And this calculation would only take place in the given window. I can already create a column that calculates sum(price_i * weight_i), but I'm stuck when it comes to correctly adding those values n times, and then dividing them by the corresponding n weights, where n is the moving average window. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the `min_weight`, `min_distance` in your code

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add the values. I edited my question.

Comment: You say "moving average" (weighted) and then you mention a window, which suggests a weighted windowed moving average. How do you define `n`, the window size?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I could have phrased that better. It's a windowed moving average with a window of n. I'd like to be able to play around with the window length and compare the difference between the simple windowed moving average and the weighted moving average.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess or suggest what `n` should be?

Comment: Well, for this sample I guess 3 is appropriate, but my real sample is much bigger and I'll be using a larger value. I was hoping for a solution that works for any window value, hence why I left the window as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think `zoo::rollapplyr` should work here. Here's a simple `n=2` window,

```r
MA <- function(X) {
  if (!is.matrix(X)) X <- matrix(X, nrow = 1)
  Hmisc::wtd.mean(X[,1], X[,2])
}
df %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  mutate(n2 = zoo::rollapplyr(
    cbind(price, weight), 2, MA,
          by.column = FALSE, partial = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 15 x 7
#       id price product reference distance weight    n2
#    <int> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     1    40 B              45    0.889  0.111  40  
#  2     2    50 B              45    1.11   1      49  
#  3     3    34 A              45    0.756  0.244  34  
#  4     4    56 B              45    1.24   1      53  
#  5     5    78 B              45    1.73   1      67  
#  6     6    35 B              45    0.778  0.222  70.2
#  7     7    23 B              45    0.511  0.489  26.8
#  8     8    40 B              45    0.889  0.111  26.1
#  9     9    50 A              45    1.11   1      46.9
# 10    10    34 B              45    0.756  0.244  35.9
# 11    11    56 B              45    1.24   1      51.7
# 12    12    78 A              45    1.73   1      64  
# 13    13    35 B              45    0.778  0.222  52.2
# 14    14    23 B              45    0.511  0.489  26.8
# 15    15    12 A              45    0.267  0.733  50.1
```

And here's a method demonstrating multiple windows in one call:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(product) %>%
  mutate(
    data.frame(lapply(
      setNames(2:4, paste0("n", 2:4)),
      function(n) zoo::rollapplyr(
        cbind(price, weight), n, MA,
        by.column = FALSE, partial = TRUE)
    ))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 15 x 9
#       id price product reference distance weight    n2    n3    n4
#    <int> <dbl> <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1     1    40 B              45    0.889  0.111  40    40    40  
#  2     2    50 B              45    1.11   1      49    49    49  
#  3     3    34 A              45    0.756  0.244  34    34    34  
#  4     4    56 B              45    1.24   1      53    52.3  52.3
#  5     5    78 B              45    1.73   1      67    61.3  60.6
#  6     6    35 B              45    0.778  0.222  70.2  63.8  59.5
#  7     7    23 B              45    0.511  0.489  26.8  56.7  56.4
#  8     8    40 B              45    0.889  0.111  26.1  28.5  55.7
#  9     9    50 A              45    1.11   1      46.9  46.9  46.9
# 10    10    34 B              45    0.756  0.244  35.9  28.4  29.8
# 11    11    56 B              45    1.24   1      51.7  50.7  43.4
# 12    12    78 A              45    1.73   1      64    60.7  60.7
# 13    13    35 B              45    0.778  0.222  52.2  49.2  48.5
# 14    14    23 B              45    0.511  0.489  26.8  43.8  42.6
# 15    15    12 A              45    0.267  0.733  50.1  50.0  48.7
```

This method takes advantage of the not-well-known behavior of `mutate` with an unname argument that returns a `data.frame`. The use of `setNames` is so that the column names are meaningfully named, there are likely other ways one might approach that.

There's not a particular reason I'm using `Hmisc::wtd.mean` over a custom function other than I know it works well. The use of the `MA` function is because within `zoo::rollapply*`, the `FUN=` argument is passed a single matrix, so we need to handle it specially, even more so because due to `partial=TRUE`, the first time `MA` is called for each group, it is passed a `vector` instead of a `matrix`.

Comment: Why do you make a one-row matrix (`if (!is.matrix(X)) X <- matrix(X, nrow = 1)`)?

Comment: I understood, it's because `rollapply` seems to convert the matrix with one row to named vector